# Querying App Data in Salesforce with Python

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, python

Currently, we're switching over to Lightning and are wanting to analyze our sales rep's Lightning usage, building predictive models to determine how successful they will be if they switch over, etc. However, the data is currently found in the "Lightning Usage" app (I'm actually not even sure if it's an app or not, but it appears to be). Regardless, I can query the data manually with Salesforce Inspector, but the "object" that the data is stored under, called LightningUsageByAppTypeMetrics, isn't a custom or standard object. So, I can't find it in the Object Manager either. It only exists within the Lightning Metrics app. Typically I would just query it like this:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

usageQuery = '''SELECT MetricsDate,user.profile.name, user.id 
FROM LightningUsageByAppTypeMetrics 
WHERE MetricsDate >= 2018-10-06 AND AppExperience = \'Lightning Experience\'

sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://<org>.lightning.force.com', 
                username=username, 
                password=password)
usageData = sf.query_all(usageQuery)
'''
```

But I get the error:

```
SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://salesforce.com.
Response content: 
[{'message': "sObject type 'LightningUsageByAppTypeMetrics' is not supported.", 
'errorCode': 'INVALID_TYPE'}]
```

I only get this error when querying on that object. Any other query, on any other standard or custom object, works fine. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I should add, I can find this object in Workbench and can query it within Workbench as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sObject [`LightningUsageByAppTypeMetrics`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebyapptypemetrics.htm) was introduced in API 43.0, but `simple_salesforce` [defaults to API 38.0](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py#L5). It can't see the sObject because it didn't exist in that API version.

To fix this, just add an `api_version` parameter to your login call:

```
sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://<org>.lightning.force.com', 
                username=username, 
                password=password,
                version='46.0')
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Thank you so much @David Reed!